# Poll and update state UNLESS a specific prop updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm building a React Native application that is polling for wallet balances every 6 seconds. I've setup a timer which I am using to 1) call ONCE initially for balance (ie. not wait 6 seconds for the interval in my timer to run) and 2) poll as normal after that.

The problem I'm having is the user can change the state while the polling is happening but because the interval is already running what happens is the user updates the state then the polling code overwrites it.

For example given `assetBalances` of:

```
{ lorem: { balance: 100 } }
```

If the user were to change the wallet name from `"lorem"` to `"ipsum"` I'd momentarily be left with `assetBalances` of:

```
{ ipsum: { balance: 100 } }
```

Which would then quickly become the following when the poll has ran. (The reason it adds to the object is because I spread with `...` as you can see in `network-scan.ts`):

```
{ lorem: { balance: 100 }, ipsum: { balance: 100 } }
```

I've tried using a custom `usePrevious` hook which compares the last prop to current prop and then I conditionally call the `setAsyncValue` in `network-scan.ts` but that didn't work.

I need a way to CANCEL the running `timer.start` instance if x prop changes (x being `assetBalances` in my first case).

On a side note I'm also having an issue where for some reason when there's lots of state changes the timer gets called multiple times which causes loads of intervals to run in parallel, which I don't understand because I'm calling `timer.stop()` at the start of every useEffect re-render - why?

If anyone has any ideas as to how I can solve these issues I'd really appreciate it! Or is there a much easier way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nature of the issue is that intervals and timers are *imperative* while react is *declarative*.

Dan Abramov has a great blog post explaining in great detail how to overcome this; the core idea being that you use a mutable ref to keep the callback and refer to it in the timer. This way you don't need to start/stop the timer each time something changes. You just need to change what the ref holds. You can read up on it [here](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

Comment: I'm on mobile, if you need more info ping me, and I'll add when I'll be on desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mordechai. Changing `clearInterval` to `clearTimeout` seems to cause the code to execute repeatedly (like an infinity loop). As for the `useTimeout` hook I've added it and I'm trying to call it in the `polling.ts` file (`useInterval(scan, intervalTime);`) instead of the timer logic, but but am getting `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component` error

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval#parameters), _the pool of IDs used by setInterval() and setTimeout() are shared, which means you can technically use clearInterval() and clearTimeout() interchangeably_.

Comment: You should replace your useEffect() in the useNetworkPolling() with the useTimeout() hook putting the actual logic as a callback of the timeout

Comment: @Basa that's interesting to hear

Comment: Fwiw polling is better suited with intervals instead of timers. So Abramov's hook would probably be better, and you no longer need to deal with starts and stops.

Comment: @Mordechai managed to get it working with the `useInterval` hook + wrapping the new state values with a couple of functions that filter the old data, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Much cleaner however with this approach you don't have an initial call like with my `timer.start(scan, 1...)` which means no result until you wait for the set interval time. Any ideas?

Comment: You could easily tweak the interval hook code to call it once before subscription to the interval. It will re-call every time the interval clears and resubscribes